# How to mock Promise resolve function in Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I'm using Jest + Enzyme.
I have a function,

```
     submitHandler = values => {
         return new Promise((resolve, _) => {
                saveSomething({values, resolve});
         }
     }
```

My test:

```
    it('Should call saveSomething on form submit', () => {
        const values = {firstName: 'FName', lastname: 'LName'};
        const {enzymeWrapper, props} = setup();
        enzymeWrapper.find('Formik').simulate('submit', values);
        expect(props.saveSomething).toBeCalledWith({
            values: {
                ...values,
                contactLanguage: LOCALE_TO_LANGUAGE_MAP[props.locale],
            },
        });
    });
```

Currently, my test is failed.
Error:

```
    Error: expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalledWith(...expected)

    - Expected
    + Received

    @@ -1,6 +1,7 @@
      Object {
    +   "resolve": [Function anonymous],
        "values": Object {
          "contactLanguage": "FRENCH",
          "firstName": "FName",
          "lastname": "LName",
        },,
```

Question: How to mock resolve function?

Comment: The code you gave is incomplete

Comment: @slideshowp2 what do you mean?

Answer (score 3):

Jest mocks have an inherent method to cope with Promise resolutions and rejections. Please refer to the [Jest Mock API](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockresolvedvaluevalue) for details.

The `mockResolvedValue` method is used for this very purpose.

Just mock your submitHandler with a simple call to `jest.fn()` and add the `mockResolvedValue` method.

You can test rejections as well with the `mockRejectValue` method.